# Processing a Message Using Twilio and WhatsApp

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to send a whatsapp message using ngrok and twilio and getting this error in PowerShell. I'm trying to do this Udemy course and running into issues with the python code: https://www.udemy.com/course/whatsapp-stock-market-bot-with-python-twilio-marketstack

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020 22:01:43] "←[35m←[1mPOST /webhook HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
[2020-11-17 22:09:34,389] ERROR in app: Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\eyr\desktop\stock_bot\env\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\EYR\Desktop\stock_bot\env\app.py", line 33, in webhook
    send_msg(response, sender)
  File "C:\Users\EYR\Desktop\stock_bot\env\app.py", line 21, in send_msg
    if msg == "hi":
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'message'
```

==============================================================================

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from twilio.rest import Client
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

ACCOUNT_ID = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT')
TWILIO_TOKEN = os.environ.get('TWILIO_TOKEN')
client = Client(ACCOUNT_ID, TWILIO_TOKEN)
TWILIO_NUMBER = 'whatsapp:+14155238886'

def send_msg(msg, recipient):
    client.message.create(
        from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
        body=msg,
        to=recipient
    )

def process_msg(msg):
    response = ""
    if msg == "hi":
        response = "Hello, welcome to the stock market bot Elyse."
    else:
        response = "Please type hi to get started."
    return response

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    f = request.form
    msg = f['Body']
    sender = f['From']
    response = process_msg(msg)
    send_msg(response, sender)
    return "OK", 200
```

Comment: Great you are getting an error. So what? What do you expect us to do about it? You have just stated you have an error and here is my code. Do you want help fixing it? Do you just want congratulations on breaking your code? What is the code even trying to do? What should it be doing? All in all **where is the question?** Please [edit] the post and also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here in the code:

Change:
`client.message.create`

To:
`client.messages.create`

Note the plural for messages.

You can find more information here, [Message Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource).